# Hide div when another div is close to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I would like to hide a div when another div is close to the top of the screen on scroll.

This is how is working at the moment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/palomatiessen/pen/vZByqR)

So when `section4` is like 100px from the top of the page, hide `bullets`.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself, **not only on a third-party site**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 100 to the `$.scrollTop()` to see when the element is 100px from the top of the page, and only fire the bullets to be hidden if they're shown (and vice versa).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastDiv = $("#section4").offset().top,
      $bullets = $('#bullets');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st + 100 >= lastDiv) { 
        $bullets.is(':visible') && $bullets.fadeOut(100);
    }
    else if ($bullets.is(':hidden')) {
      $bullets.fadeIn(100); 
     }
   });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#section1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

nav#bullets {
 position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 999;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

nav#bullets span {
 cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 15px 5px;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

nav#bullets span:after {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
nav#bullets span:hover {
    background-color: white;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="bullets">
        <a href="#section1"><span></span></a>
        <a href="#section2"><span></span></a>
        <a href="#section<nav id="bullets">
  <a href="#section1"><span></span></a>
  <a href="#section2"><span></span></a>
  <a href="#section3"><span></span></a>
  <a href="#section4"><span></span></a>
</nav>

<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div id="section1" class="section" data-hash="a">
    <div>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="section4" class="footer">
  <div>
    <h1>Section 4</h1>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
    <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
  </div>
</div>3"><span></span></a>
        <a href="#section4"><span></span></a>
    </nav>

<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div id="section1" class="section" data-hash="a">
   <div>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="section4" class="footer">
  <div>
   <h1>Section 4</h1>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
   <p>This section is not inside the section wrapper, so normal scrolling here!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```